# A grammar whose language is a set of even numbers

Tags: automata, context-free-grammar

I want to construct a context free grammar for a language which is a set of even numbers.
Here is my attempt

s:> 0T0|T2T4T6T8|£

where £ is an empty string

T:> 2|4|6|8|

please i need something better than this

Comment: Are you looking for a grammar for the set of _decimal representations_ of even natural numbers? That's any sequence of (even or odd) digits, followed by an even digit.

Comment: No, what i need is a grammar when evaluated can produce a set of even numbers ie 0,2,4,6,8.......

Comment: How does that differ from what I was saying?

Comment: If you're trying to solve a homework exercise, it may help to quote the exact text of the exercise you're given, even if it's in a language other than English. If this is _not_ homework, please explain what you're doing and what you need this grammar for.

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes that you want the numbers to appear in a canonical form, i.e. without leading zero-digits.

The set of decimal representations of even numbers is equivalent to the union of $\left\{0\right\}$ and the set of digit streams beginning with $\left\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\right\}$ and ending with $\left\{0, 2, 4, 6, 8\right\}$. This is a Strictly Local (and thus Regular) stringset.  Any Regular stringset can be recognized (or generated) by a left- or right-linear CFG.  A left-linear grammar for this particular set is:

> $$\begin{align}
>   S &\to T0 \mathrel{|} T2 \mathrel{|} T4 \mathrel{|} T6 \mathrel{|} T8\\
>   T &\to U \mathrel{|} \varepsilon\\
>   U &\to U0 \mathrel{|} T1 \mathrel{|} T2 \mathrel{|} T3 \mathrel{|} T4 \mathrel{|} T5 \mathrel{|} T6 \mathrel{|} T7 \mathrel{|} T8 \mathrel{|} T9
>  \end{align}$$

This essentially builds strings from the right.  $S$ begins the process by rewriting to a $T$ followed by an even digit.  Since the final digit is even, the generated number will be even no matter what $T$ rewrites to.  The job of $T$ is to decide whether to terminate the string (by becoming $\varepsilon$) or place more digits (by becoming $U$).

Whenever $U$ appears, it will continue generating the number by placing one additional digit.  If that digit is a (leading) zero, it is preceded by another $U$, else by a $T$.  Since $U$ must place at least one digit, this prevents generation of leading zeroes.

Suppose you want to generate $2048$.  A derivation follows:

> $$\begin{align}
>     \color{red}{S} &\to \color{red}{T8}\\
>     \color{red}{T}8  &\to \color{red}{U}8\\
>     \color{red}{U}8  &\to \color{red}{T4}8\\
>     \color{red}{T}48  &\to \color{red}{U}48\\
>     \color{red}{U}48  &\to \color{red}{U0}48\\
>     \color{red}{U}048  &\to \color{red}{T2}048\\
>     \color{red}{T}2048  &\to \color{red}{\varepsilon}2048\\
>     \color{red}{\varepsilon}2048  &=2048
>  \end{align}$$